# SUM e GROUP BY no SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho 2 tabelas: **pedido de compra** e **itens do pedido de compra**. Nem todos os pedidos tem todos os itens faturados de uma só vez, posso ter por exemplo um pedido com 5 linhas, onde 2 já foram faturadas e 3 ainda estão em aberto. Preciso gerar uma consulta que retorne o valor total solicitado no pedido, o valor já faturado/liquidado e o valor em aberto.
Fiz a consulta mas ela está retornando 2 linhas distintas para a mesma ordem, uma delas somente com o valor faturado e outra com o valor em aberto:

[image: Resultado obtido com a Query]

O resultado que espero é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A consulta que construí:

```
SELECT
  pedido.ID_PEDIDO ID_REGISTRO,
  pedido.ORDEM_COMPRA ORDEM,
  SUM(NVL(item.PRECO_UNITARIO,0) * NVL(item.QUANTIDADE,0)) VALOR_TOTAL,
  CASE WHEN item.STATUS= 'RESERVED' THEN SUM(NVL(item.PRECO_UNITARIO,0) * NVL(item.QUANTIDADE,0)) END ABERTO,
  CASE WHEN item.STATUS= 'LIQUIDATED' THEN SUM(NVL(item.PRECO_UNITARIO,0) * NVL(item.QUANTIDADE,0)) END FATURADO
FROM
  tblPedidos pedido,
  tblPedidosItens item
WHERE 
  pedido.ID_PEDIDO = item.ID_PEDIDO
GROUP BY
  pedido.ID_PEDIDO ,
  pedido.ORDEM_COMPRA ,
  item.STATUS
ORDER BY 
  pedido.ORDEM_COMPRA
```

Acredito que o problema esteja no `GROUP BY item.STATUS`, mas como faço para juntar essas duas linhas e chegar no resultado esperado?

Comment: Creio que o  item.STATUS está sobrando no GROUP BY,

Comment: @Motta se tirar o item.STATUS, retorna o erro ORA-00979: não é uma expressão GROUP BY

Comment: Tenta o case assim ( sum  "fora") ... SUM(CASE WHEN item.STATUS= 'RESERVED' THEN (NVL(item.PRECO_UNITARIO,0) * NVL(item.QUANTIDADE,0)) END) ABERTO

Comment: @Motta consegui! Só fiz algumas adaptações no seu exemplo, o código ficou assim: 
SUM(NVL(CASE WHEN item.STATUS = 'RESERVED' THEN item.PRECO_UNITARIO * item.QUANTIDADE END,0)) ABERTO
Também tirei o GROUP BY item.STATUS, com essa adaptação do código ele ficou sobrando mesmo.
Valeu!!

Comment: Publica a solução , esta dúvida é recorrente.

Answer (score -2):

Resolução do problema: a função `SUM()` deve cercar os `CASE... END` e o campo `item.Status` deve ser removido da cláusula `GROUP BY`.